# Linking bare repo to actual repo in Git and post-receive hooks

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

So far from reading the git tutorails I have understood that for sharing my project files residing in my ubuntu linux server I need to create a bare repository and link it to the actual repository, so that when users clone the actual repo they get the actual repo having the actual work files.

And when they push their changes to the server the post-receive hook now updates the actual repo containing work files.

This is all I could understand and beyound that I have a lot of confusion for which I have the foll questions:

```
1) How do I create my bare repo.
2) How do I link it to the actual repo consisting the actual work files.
3) And what is this post-receive hook? Where does it reside? And what configurations do I need to do for the same.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I create my bare repo.

Read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).

To clone **existing** repository into a new `bare` repo, you would run this command:

```
git clone --bare my_project my_project.git
```

> How do I link it to the actual repo consisting the actual work files.

Read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

The `non-bare` repository can add the `bare` as a `remote`:

```
git remote add <name> <remote-URL>
```

Then, from the `non-bare`:

```
git push <name-of-remote> <branch-to-push-from>:<remote-branch-to-push-to>.
```

Again, this is all covered in the [Git SCM book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), which I **recommend you read before asking the same question again on StackOverflow**.

Read the book. It gives you the terms to search for (such as `git remote repositories`, `git bare server`, etc). There are *lots* of questions on StackOverflow about this, when you know what to search for.

> And what is this post-receive hook?

It's a script that is run after the repository is `push`ed to. (After it has received data, the repository runs the `post-receive` script - sensible naming).

> Where does it reside?

In the `hooks` directory of the `bare` repository; in `.git/hooks` otherwise. Read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

> And what configurations do I need to do for the same.

**You do not need a `post-receive` hook** to do what you're asking to do (set up a basic `bare` repository so a small number of multiple users can `git push` and `git pull` from it). If you do not know what a `hook` is, **you do not need one** at this point. Set up your repository, get comfortable using basic git commands and working with collaborators on a `bare` repo, and ask a specific question about setting up and using a `post-receive` hook.

I can't stress this enough: **read the book**. It will help. I learned a lot. :) It **will** tell you how to:

1. How do I create my bare repo. (This is [`Chapter 4`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server)).
2. How do I link it to the actual repo consisting the actual work files. (This is [`Chapter 2, section 5`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)).
3. And what is this post-receive hook? Where does it reside? And what configurations do I need to do for the same. (This is [`Chapter 7, section 3`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)).

Comment: You have a lot of patience.  I hope it's worth it.

Comment: @simont: Thanks a lot for you effort and patience.I'll follow you suggestions ang get back if I face any issues.

Comment: @gautamvegeta Heh. I *struggled* with `git` for several months before I read that silly book - it *really* helped me. Some of the concepts are a little tough to understand, but when you get your head around them they're really neat and sensible. Apologies if this answer seemed impatient - reading the book, slowly, and giving yourself time to understand will really help. Also, making a few practice repositories is also useful. :) Plus, if you get super stuck, StackOverflow will answer most of your questions pretty fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `.git` folder is the real repository.  It will be a folder in the working folder locally, but a bare repository doesn't have a working folder so it has a .git extension.

A bare repository is one without a work folder (i.e. where the files are checked out).  To create a bare repository use `git init --bare <repository name>`.

When working locally, a `git clone <repository path> <working folder>` is executed to make a local copy of the remote repository.  This is then updated on regular basis with `git fetch` or `git pull` and change are applied back to the server with `git pull`.  Cloning a repository locally creates a name for it called a remote, this name is `origin`.

A branch is basically a named path of development and is created with the `git branch` command.  Linking a local branch with a remote branch tells git what to default to when fetching, and pushing and can simplify the commands used.  To link, or track, a remote branch use `git branch -u <remote>/<branch>`.

There is no reason to get involved with git's various hooks for any of these basic operations.

The [git book](http://www.git-scm.com/book) covers these basic operations well.